# Using in-memory sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, in-memory

I've been reading, browsing, searching a lot on this, I've criss-crossed stackoverflow back and forth many times and I managed to narrow my problem as much as I could.

The only thing I do not understand, is how to fully use an in-memory SQLite database.

Here is my situation - I have an encrypted SQLite database which I decrypt during the loading of my application (this part works for sure). My class that interacts with the database works for sure with a plain database.
So to make it short, everything is flawless with a plain DB which gets loaded from the internal phone memory, but I am not sure how or where to store the decrypted DB in memory so it would get interpreted as normal DB.

I guess I should put `null` instead of a name in `super(context, null, null, 3);` and use `:memory:` instead of a path in `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()`, but I still don't understand fully. It says it cannot find an `android_metadata` table, but I am certain the database is as it should be.

Hope I was clear on this :)

Comment: Tried [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/)?

Comment: I haven't given much thought. I kinda didn't find it when I first was researching, so I developed my own 2-step "encryption". Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.
Can you tell me how secure is SQLCipher and does it compress data?

Comment: 256-bit AES encryption is ok - and you're not likely to make a better implementation on your own I'd wager.

Answer (score 32):

[SQLiteOpenHelper()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) will create an in-memory database if the `name` is `null`. Note that it will be created when you invoke `getWritableDatabase()`.

Then you should insert your data.

Answer (score 12):

You (or the framework) create a database using **ONE** of the following:

- `SQLiteDatabase.create()`
- `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()`
- `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase()`

The first option is the only way to create a memory-only database, the other two open or create a database file.

Consequently, if you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper()` and you pass `name` as `null`, the framework calls `SQLiteDatabase.create(null)`, so you will get a database that only lives in memory (it dies when `close()` is called).  There is no need to also call one of the other direct methods.  Instead call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` from your helper.

Comment: ok then, how do I use a database after I call `myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.create(null);`? I have the decrypted DB as raw bytes in another class, how do I merge those bytes into the DB handle that was created?

Comment: I don't believe sqlite3 supports "opening" a :memory: database from an existing blob, so APIs in Android to do so likely don't exist either. Your best bet may be to stream your decrypted database out to a file where it can be opened with a valid path using `openDatabase()`.  If you don't want to have the decrypted database persisted, you could copy the data into the memory-only version using queries/inserts and then close/remove the file version.

Comment: @Devunwired, when you say "it dies when `close()` is called", are you referring to `SQLiteOpenHelper.close()`, or `SQLiteDatabase.close()`? Will closing a database connection (via `SQLiteDatabase.close()`) destroy the database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be carefull wile using inmemory as your data will be lost once the db connection is lost. Make sure your db instance is not been closed

https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: usually in-memory db are useful for mocking test instances.

Comment: Yes and even for reducing the read/write cycle to ROM.