# Organizing data layer in android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I have problems in designing data layer for android applications. More precisely I don't understand what query-like functions should return. I had such solution:

```
public class NotesDatabase {
    // ...
    public Cursor queryAllNotes() {
        return helper.getReadableDatabase().query(...);
    }
}
```

There's problem in this approach. To use result you must know query: columns and their types. It's violation of encapsulation. Also this approach creates problems for unit testing.

But I saw another approach:

```
public class NotesDatabase {
    // ...
    public List<Note> queryAllNotes() {
        Cursor c = helper.getReadableDatabase().query(...);
        ArrayList<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>(c.getCount());
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            notes.add(new Note(c.getInt(), c.getText() ...));
        }
        return notes;
    }
}
```

At least we keep encapsulation but I see other problems here. It doesn't seem to be memory performant approach. I can't use CursorAdapter and CursorLoader, can't set autorequerying which is not actually a problem. What a problem is big results. What to do if response is too big to fit in memory? Should I prevent such situation? <strike>Should I care?</strike>

So which approach is preferable? And how to solve these issues?

Comment: Actually I don't get your question.

Comment: @juergend My question is how to organize query functions in data layer to keep encapsulation and how to deal with big results of queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the second approach would provide a better encapsulation since the caller would be dealing with a list of familiar domain model (Note) objects instead of a database cursor. To handle the problem of large data sets, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465252/should-we-interact-with-a-db-storage-often-in-android/38536884#38536884) may be helpful.