# When SQLiteOutOfMemoryException will be thrown

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using [insertOrThrow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method to insert the data into [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). Thrown Exceptions are handled manullay to make sure that the given value is inserted into db.

Exceptions like [SQLiteFullException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteFullException.html), [SQLiteDiskIOException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDiskIOException.html) are having some description in [android developer site](https://developer.android.com/index.html) to refer.

But for [SQLiteOutOfMemoryException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOutOfMemoryException.html) no description is there to refer.
Does anyone knows when this [SQLiteOutOfMemoryException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOutOfMemoryException.html) will be thrown. If anyone knows, please share it.

Comment: Whenever underlaing c/c++ library would return SQLITE_NOMEM

Answer (score 3):

It should happen when your sqlite DB size goes beyond your heap size, `SQLiteOpenHelper()` will create an in-memory database if the `name` is `null`. try using largeHeap in your manifest or don't create in-memory DB

Comment: when you create it in memory, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657191/using-in-memory-sqlite-android

Comment: @masoudvali So SQLiteOutOfMemoryException will happens only for the in-memory type not for the file type database

Comment: yes, and avoid storing large strings or bytearrays in your DB

Comment: *So SQLiteOutOfMemoryException will happens only for the in-memory type*  **no**

Comment: @Selvin no it's just one of the cases when it happens, I don't know about other cases

Comment: *I don't know about other cases* it doesn't makes answer yes ... obviously it may happend whenever sqlite3_malloc() or sqlite3_realloc() has failed ... and yes @psink you are right about heap ... native heap has nothing to do with Art/dalvik heap and sqlite mostly using native

Comment: @Selvin If you know any better answer, inform us. Try helping others instead of complaining

Comment: Only you are complaining, I already wrote when it is thrown in the comment ... and using largeHeap is a poor man's choice

Answer (score 1):

There are some restrictions on size of the SQlite database in android.
**SQLiteOutOfMemoryException** will arise when the database size exceed from 4 MB that I have tested on the below kitkat but on marshmellow it arise over 9 MB.It also depends on the available free space for run your application.
    So keep your database under the 4 MB.
    Always Take proper backup of your database in file and sync with your application server as per the application requirement.
    Never Store the images in the SQlite DB either in BLOB or in Base64 String Format.

Comment: 4MB for a in-memory DB I guess.

Comment: Yes.For best practice always keep your under 4 MB and avoid storing large Strings .

Comment: For best practice, use a file ;) And your answer doesn't specify the storage of your database. So from what I can see, you are telling that a SQlite database can't store anything above 9MB ...

Comment: You can use File System to store large amount of data.Write your db content with proper String  delemeters for separation of the data.

Comment: Using a file to store the SQlite database ... not to create your own database.

Comment: Another way to store large amount of data in SQlite DB is put your db file in the external storage and store data till the External Storage not fill.Enjoy.